# How to recreate activity from another activity when enable/disable Night mode?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme

I have found many questions related to this but my problem is a little bit different.

From SettingActivity, I enable/disable the nigh mode through the following code:

```
ApplicationClass.setNightMode();
ApplicationClass.setDayMode();
```

Actuall code written in application class.

But when I return back to MainActivity from SettingActivity the color does not change of layout because of onCreate() method do not call.

How can I recreate the MainActivity from SettingActivity when I enable/disable night mode.

My Application code from where I enable and disable night mode:

```
    public static void setNightMode(){
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }

    public static void setDayMode(){
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }
```

Comment: you can set the call to disabling the night mode in MainActivity in onResume, check the android acitvity lifecycle : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: @medyas What do you mean?  Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Your `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);` should be on the Application level. And than it won't be a problem when turning back or going forward to any activity between your app. Don't forget to register it to the manifest.

Example:

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //give a start value AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }

    public static void setNightMode(){
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }

    public static void setDayModeOrSth(){
        //AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }
}
```

And in your manifest file:

```
<application
            android:name="package.name.TestApplication"
```

And than on your Acivity/Fragments

```
Testapplication.setDayModeOrSth();
```

or

```
Testapplication.setNightMode();
```

Exuse my stupid naming and example :) But it would be something like that. Good luck.

Comment: can you please share or give an example?

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work. I updated the question with code. You can look at it.

Comment: in your `onResume` place this: `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode())`

Comment: Added the following code in MainActivity onResume() but still didn't work
`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode());`

Comment: Than I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

if you recreating the MainActivity you will lose it's current state so you can try overriding onResume and check whether you need to enable/disable night mode:

```
public class MainAcitivy extends ... {

    .....

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(nightModeOn) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        }
}
```

The other solution is to start a new MainActivity by overriding the onBackPressed in SettingActivity and start MainActivity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends .. {

    .....

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finishAffinity();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the onConfigurationChanged method of activity.

`public abstract void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)`

Comment: You don't need to recreate activity. just implement the onConfigurationChanged method, control will automatically transfer there whenever config get changed

Comment: Can you share any example of this?